# How can i iterate throught my emf model from a gmf editor without parsing the xml model file?

Tags: eclipse, modeling, eclipse-emf, eclipse-gmf

I have successfully created a GMF editor which draws models based on my EMF model.What i wanted to do is to iterate through my model's EClasses .Can this be achieved at runtime through my plugin code without having to read the xml file that the gmf editor creates ?Is there such an API from EMF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate test code from the genmodel file then inside the XYZ.test plugin there is such type of code that i was searching.It traverses through the xmi file of your model

```
// Create a resource set to hold the resources.
    //
    ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();

    // Register the appropriate resource factory to handle all file extensions.
    //
    resourceSet.getResourceFactoryRegistry().getExtensionToFactoryMap().put
        (Resource.Factory.Registry.DEFAULT_EXTENSION, 
         new XMIResourceFactoryImpl());

    // Register the package to ensure it is available during loading.
    //
    resourceSet.getPackageRegistry().put
        (XYZmetamodelPackage.eNS_URI, 
         XYZmetamodelPackage.eINSTANCE);

    // If there are no arguments, emit an appropriate usage message.
    //
    if (args.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("Enter a list of file paths or URIs that have content like this:");
        try {
            Resource resource = resourceSet.createResource(URI.createURI("http:///My.metamodel"));
            ModelObject root = atagmetamodelFactory.eINSTANCE.createModelObject();
            resource.getContents().add(root);
            resource.save(System.out, null);
        }
        catch (IOException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        // Iterate over all the arguments.
        //
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
            // Construct the URI for the instance file.
            // The argument is treated as a file path only if it denotes an existing file.
            // Otherwise, it's directly treated as a URL.
            //
            File file = new File(args[i]);
            URI uri = file.isFile() ? URI.createFileURI(file.getAbsolutePath()): URI.createURI(args[i]);

            try {
                // Demand load resource for this file.
                //
                Resource resource = resourceSet.getResource(uri, true);
                System.out.println("Loaded " + uri);

                // Validate the contents of the loaded resource.
                //
                for (EObject eObject : resource.getContents()) {
                    Diagnostic diagnostic = Diagnostician.INSTANCE.validate(eObject);
                    if (diagnostic.getSeverity() != Diagnostic.OK) {
                        printDiagnostic(diagnostic, "");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (RuntimeException exception) {
                System.out.println("Problem loading " + uri);
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```